# JQuery CSS menu issue when menu item is active

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using a JQuery based css menu for my website. My problem however is if I click on one off the menu items. I want it to stay a cetain color, in my case the borrom half off the images.

I got my code from http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/ I used the second example. Heres the example page: http://snook.ca/technical/jquery-bg/

My code looks as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

        $('#nav a')
            .css( {backgroundPosition: "-20px 35px"} )
            .mouseover(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-20px 94px)"}, {duration:800})
        })
            .mouseout(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(40px 35px)"}, {duration:800, complete:function(){
                    $(this).css({backgroundPosition: "-20px 35px"})
                }})


        })
        });
    </script>
```

If you hover over the menu the menu will change to a different color, that's the color I want the menu to stay when the menu is active and has been clicked on.

Hope someone could help me.

I tried as the answer said and still nothing

My modified code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

    $('#nav a')
        .css( {backgroundPosition: "-20px 35px"} )
        .mouseover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-20px 94px)"}, {duration:800})
    })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(40px 35px)"}, {duration:800, complete:function(){
                $(this).css({backgroundPosition: "-20px 35px"})
            }})


    })

    $('#nav a').click(function() {
         $('#nav a:not(.selected');
        $('#nav a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    })


    });



</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add a CSS class to the clicked links, not unlike this:

```
$('#nav a').click(function() {
    $('#nav a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
})
```

Then, you can have a CSS declaration like:

```
.selected { background-position: -20px 35px; }
```

And finally, the mouseOver and mouseOut functions should be set to `$('#nav a:not(.selected')`, if you don't want the CSS to be overwritten.

[EDIT]
Here's the complete code:

```
$(function(){

    $('#nav a:not(.selected)')
        .css( {backgroundPosition: "-20px 35px"} )
        .live('mouseover', function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-20px 94px)"}, {duration:800})
        })
        .live('mouseout', function(){
            $(this).stop()
                .animate({
                    backgroundPosition:"(40px 35px)"},
                    {duration:800, complete:function(){
                        $(this).css({backgroundPosition: "-20px 35px"});
                }})
    })

    $('#nav a')
         .live('click', function() {
             $('#nav a').removeClass('selected');
             $(this).addClass('selected');
         });
});
```

Comment: @Alex, please change to a live() event for mouseover and mouseout and I'll give you a +1

Comment: I tried this but somehow does not seem to work

I added my code at the bottom of my answer

Comment: @cballou: done!
@Roland: please try the complete code sample I posted

Comment: I think it never gets to the click event, I tried adding in an alert like this $('#nav a')
         .live('click', function() {
  alert('sa');
             $('#nav a').removeClass('selected');
             $(this).addClass('selected');
         });
and the alert is never triggered

Comment: You could try making it a non-live event and cancel it, maybe navigation is the problem.  $('#nav a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $('#nav a').removeClass('selected'); $(this).addClass('selected'); });

Answer (score 1):

With Alexander's code to add a selected class when items are selected you should be able to modify the mouse out listener like so:

```
.mouseout(function(){
    // cache $(this) rather than executing it multiple times
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.is('.selected')) {
        $this.stop().animate(
            {
                backgroundPosition:"(40px 35px)"
            }, 
            {
                duration:800, 
                complete:function()
                {
                    $this.css({backgroundPosition: "-20px 35px"})
                }
            }
    )
})
```

Hope it helps!